# Read Native accessing large file

Tags: react-native, large-files

I have a 8MB JSON file I need to access once when my application is opened.

Having the file in native assets and reading it over bridge is too slow. Using react-native-fetch-blob, the file is read by android in less than half second, then invoking resolve on the Promise (from Java) takes about 15 seconds.

Having it as a JSON file in the JS space, I cannot build the project, getting the error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

The same issue is reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12590), but no progress.

Anyone has faced this problem before?

Comment: I faced with same issue a few weeks ago. My file was about 3mb. First I tried using json data in a module and exported it. It worked but it increased reloading time so much. Secondly I added quotes to make json object to a string then tried to jsonparse at launching but since my data was not so stable it failed too. Thirdly I tried to use file as .json  file but it also increased reloading time too. One and first solutions did not make any trouble in apk but i had white screen error in ipa. My final solution was getting data just once from web service and setting it with async storage.

Comment: I have been taking the data from web service as well, but that also is unacceptably slow, and I also need the data available offline.

Comment: Once you get data from web service app can work offline just keep it in asyncstorage but youneed at least one web request. You may want to use a db plugin like sqlite but I'm not sure if these tools can work your solution

Comment: Async storage has size limit on Android, and 8mb is over that. I am hoping I will manage to overcome the memory issue described above

Comment: Or just try to split your JSON object to smaller objects and store them to the async storage. I did this too with one of my apps, there were a lot of images(in base64) and strings and I just saved every image separated and every data separated too.